# Tag some selected words in a file using python

Tags: python-3.x

A text file contains words with brackets i.e.'[Rahul] is a good batsman'. I want to identify the bracketed words and tagged them with '\O' sign i.e. the output will be 'Rahul\O is a good boy'.
How can i do it.
input: [Rahul] is a good batsman. #written in a file

output: Rahul\O is a good batsman. #written in a file

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\[([A-Za-z ]+)\]',r'\1\O', '[Rahul] is a good batsman')
'Rahul\\O is a good batsman'
```